# Stability of higher order ODE's, positive coefficients proof

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

> Given some linear constant coefficient DE with:
>
> $$
> (a_0D^n+a_1D^{n-1}+...+a_{n-1}D+a_n)y=f(t) \tag{1}
> $$
>
> Without loss of generality, we may assume that $a_0>0$, then:
>   $$
> \textit{(1) is stable} \Rightarrow a_0,...,a_n >0
> $$

I've found the above [statement](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-ii-second-order-constant-coefficient-linear-equations/gain-and-phase-lag/MIT18_03SCF11_s15_1atext.pdf) on the MIT online course on ODE's. Since there is no analytic way of finding the roots of an n-order polynomial, I've tried proving it by rewriting the characteristic equation in Horner's scheme for some root $Re{\lambda_i}<0$ (since it's stable, all roots must have negative real part) - but without success. I also lack any intuition for why this statement should be true. Any hints on how to prove it?

Comment: You can maybe do https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle if you have done one complex variable. (enclosing the left half plane, that is)

Comment: Prove it from what starting point? I assume you want to start with something like "all the roots have negative real part" and then arrive at "$a_0,\ldots,a_n > 0$" (and vice versa)?

Comment: @Winther Yes, exactly that. I thought it was clear from the $\lambda_i <0$ in my description.

Comment: @Winther I don't see it sorry. By $f(x)$ you mean the linear operator, not the input right? If you know the proof and it seems trivial, why don't you add an answer? I'd accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characteristic equation of the homogenous DE is

$$P(x) = a_0 x^n + a_{1}x^{n-1} + \ldots + a_n$$

As you say; the DE is stable if all the roots of $P(x)$ have negative real part (this is the [Routh–Hurwitz stability criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%E2%80%93Hurwitz_stability_criterion)). One way to see this is as follows: if a root $\lambda$ has positive real part then the general solution of the DE will contain a term $Ae^{\lambda t}$ which grows without bounds as $t\to\infty$. Now pick initial conditions such that $A = 0$ then (assuming for simplicity here that $\lambda$ is the only root with positive real part) the solution will be bounded for all $t$. However if we tweek the initial conditions just slightly such that $A \not = 0$ then no matter how small $A$ is the solution will diverge as $t\to\infty$. This is incompatible with stability.

Now to the proof. Assume all roots of $P(x)$ have $\text{Re}(\lambda) < 0$ and $a_0 > 0$. We start by factorizing $P(x)$. If a root $\lambda$ is real then $P(x)$ is divisible by $(x-\lambda)$. If $\lambda$ is imaginary then since $P(x)$ is a real polynomial $(a_i\in \mathbb{R})$ we have that the complex conjugate $\lambda^*$ is also a root so $P(x)$ is divisible by

$$(x-\lambda)(x-\lambda^*) =x^2 - 2\text{Re}(\lambda)x + |\lambda|^2$$

It follows that we can factorize $P(x)$ as follows:

$$P(x) = a_0\prod_{i\,:\,\lambda_i \in\mathbb{R}} (x-\lambda_i)\cdot \prod_{i\,:\,\text{Im}(\lambda_i)>0}(x^2  - 2\text{Re}(\lambda_i)x + |\lambda_i|^2)$$

Since we know that $\text{Re}(\lambda_i) < 0$ we have that $x^2 - 2\text{Re}(\lambda)x + |\lambda|^2 = x^2 + 2|\text{Re}(\lambda)|x + |\lambda|^2$ so we see that all the terms in all the factors in the expression above are positive so if we now imagine multiplying out the product above we would get

$$P(x) = a_0 x^n + (\text{positive})x^{n-1} + \ldots + (\text{positive})$$

and it follows that $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n > 0$.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I believe there's a typo: I can't edit it but in the second sentence it should be "if all the roots of $P(x)$ have **negative** real part."

Comment: @itsok-dontworry Thanks, I fixed the typo.

Comment: What if $Re(\lambda_i)$ equals to zero?

Comment: @Yola In that case we only get $a_i \geq 0$. For stability in this case see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%E2%80%93Hurwitz_stability_criterion